# Efficient alternatives to qualified Haskell list comprehensions

Tags: performance, haskell, list-comprehension

As an illustration of qualified list comprehensions in Haskell, the [Learn You a Haskell](http://learnyouahaskell.com/starting-out#tuples) tutorial provides an example of list comprehension that suggests a general approach to finding the right triangles with a given perimeter `p`, expressed as a tuple:

```
λ> let rightTriangles p = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..(quot p 2)], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b], a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a + b + c == p]
```

But this approach becomes *very* slow as `p` gets large.

Is there a generally faster yet idiomatic Haskell way to accomplish the same thing for large `p`?

Comment: I think the general idea is to use a different algorithm, i.e. not brute force.  It's not the list comprehension at fault for this being slow, this is a classic example of a brute force algorithm of nested for loops.  The complexity of this algorithm is somewhere around `O(n^3)`, not a good complexity to have as `n` grows larger.

Comment: Right, this is an algorithms/math problem not a Haskell/performance problem. How interested are you in solving this particular problem of finding right triangles with prescribed perimeter? The efficient way is to use the parameterization of Pythagorean triples and start by factoring `p`...

Comment: @ReidBarton: Yes, good points, which partially answer the question: The constraints are not applied to the domain specifications. For example all values of `(a, b, c)` for ` c <- [1..(quot p 2)]`, `b <- [1..c]`, and `a <- [1..b]` will be examined, and *then* then constraints are applied (in contrast, to say, limiting `a` to values equal to `p-c-b`. That was the Haskell-y question I was asking.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The comments make the good point that what you really need is a better algorithm.

But let's try something different, and see what optimizations we can make to the current code:

```
let rightTrianglesCubic p = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..quot p 2], b <- [1..c], a <- [1..b], a^2 + b^2 == c^2, a + b + c == p]
```

First, note how we're looping over all the values of `[1..b]` until we find one where `a + b + c == p`. But the only value where that holds is `a = p - b - c`, so we can skip the loop altogether, and make this into a quadratic algorithm:

```
let rightTrianglesQuadraticA p = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..quot p 2], b <- [1..c], let a = p - b - c, a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

There's a slight problem with this approach:

```
λ rightTrianglesCubic 120
[(30,40,50),(24,45,51),(20,48,52)]
λ rightTrianglesQuadraticA 120
[(40,30,50),(30,40,50),(45,24,51),(24,45,51),(48,20,52),(20,48,52),(0,60,60)]
```

We get some extra results! This is because we ignored the implicit conditions made by `a <- [1..b]`, namely `1 <= a` and `a <= b`. So let's add those back in.

```
let rightTrianglesQuadraticB p = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..quot p 2], b <- [1..c], let a = p - b - c, a^2 + b^2 == c^2, 1 <= a, a <= b]
```

And now we get the right answer:

```
λ rightTrianglesQuadraticB 120
[(30,40,50),(24,45,51),(20,48,52)]
```

Since each value of `b` has a unique `a`, the conditions `1 <= a` and `a <= b`
can be phrased as conditions on `b`. `1 <= a` is the same as `1 <= p - b - c` or
`b <= p - c - 1`. `a <= b` is the same as `p - b - c <= b` or `p - c <= 2*b` or
`div (p - c + 1) 2 <= b`.

This lets us shrink the bounds on the loop `b <- [1..c]`:

```
let rightTrianglesQuadraticC p = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1..quot p 2], b <- [max 1 (div (p - c + 1) 2) .. min c (p - c - 1) ], let a = p - b - c, a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

We can even shrink the bounds on `c <- [1..quot p 2]` by noting that in order for `a < b < c` with `a+b+c == p`, we must have `c > p/3`:

```
let rightTrianglesQuadraticD p = [ (a,b,c) | c <- [1 + quot p 3..quot p 2], b <- [max 1 (div (p - c + 1) 2) .. min c (p - c - 1) ], let a = p - b - c, a^2 + b^2 == c^2]
```

This is about as far as optimizing this particular code can go. For further performance improvement, we'll need to switch algorithms altogether.

Comment: Thanks. This is exactly what I was looking for: I wanted to stick with a list comprehension, but don't want to to be *O(n³)*. I also wanted to confirm what I was wondering: that the constraints after `|` are not "solved" in any way (as you have done "by hand" above).